# convert files with using basename to different externsion

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure this out.

I've found multiple ways to do this but always result in the files being named `.mp4.png`

here is my command script:

`find -name "*.mp4" -type f|xargs -i ffmpeg -i {} -r 0.0033 -vf scale=-1:1024 -vcodec png $(basename {} .mp4).png`

I also tried this but it doesn't work very well

`find . -type f -iname \*.mp4 | while read -r file`
`do`
 `echo "Converting $file"  | cut -f 1 -d '.'`

`ffmpeg -i $file -r 0.0033 -vf scale=-1:1024 -vcodec png "$file" | "cut -f 1 -d '.'".png`

`done`

Answer (score 1):

This formulation comes from the post
[How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784661/how-do-you-convert-an-entire-directory-with-ffmpeg):

```
for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Another code fragment is:

```
for i in *.avi;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  ffmpeg -i "$i" "${name}.mov"
done
```

Comment: this works very well - although it's not recursive.

Comment: @user2179760 You didn't mention that it was required to be recursive in the question.